# How to add custom font in magento2 transactional email?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, fonts

I am trying to add custom fonts in magento 2 transactional emails however, it does not work. I am using hyva theme.

I have imported Sofia-pro font under app/design/frontend///web/fonts/SofiaProRegular.woff2 and app/design/frontend///web/fonts/Sofia_pro_regular.ttf

Then I have added _typography.less file under app/design/frontend///web/css/source/_typography.less and added the following code in it

```
.lib-font-face {
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base;
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/SofiaProRegular.woff2';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

After that, I added the following code inside _variable.less

```
@font-family-name__base:'Sofia-pro';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
```

Then tried using in my less file as,

```
body {
font-family: 'Sofia-pro', Sans-serif';
}
```

But, none of that seems to work, the font is not applied into my email template.

How do I apply custom fonts in my transactional email templates in magento 2?

My magento 2 version is magento 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SofiaProRegular.woff` and `SofiaProRegular.woff2` for fonts files. Your font path in your code is incorrect, this patch shouldn't use the file extension.

To achieve your goal, take the following step:

1. Add font files to your local theme directory. For example, `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/fonts`.
2. Create `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_typography.less` file

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Sofia-pro',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/SofiaProRegular',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
);
```

3. Create `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_email.less` file

```
.wrapper-inner {
    .main-content, p, th, td {
        font-family: 'Sofia-pro', 'Sans-serif';
    }
}
```

You're done.

Related document:

- Use custom fonts in email template in Magento 2: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email/#custom-fonts
- Add a new custom font in magento 2: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/fonts/

Comment: There is no vendor/hyva-themes/web in my vendor dir. I already have _typography.less file included under source dir and I added this code, it still does not work. I also tried using adobe typekit web fonts link into my header.html file but, that also does not work.

Comment: I don't have Hyva theme, I've tested the code I give you in the answer with a custom theme based on Magento/luma (it also works for Magento/blank) with the hope it will work with Hyva. Try to create `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_variables.less` with the below content:

Comment: `@font-family-name__base: 'Sofia-pro';`
`@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;`

Comment: If it still does not work, could you share a screenshot of the theme structure? So I can help.

Comment: That did not work either, U can find my custom theme structure here: [link](https://imgur.com/a/9iisb4Y) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: I mean the theme structure of Hyva theme, not your custom theme. Do you need to override CSS in 3 files `_email-*.less`? If not, try to remove these files and test. As I read from Hyva document, my solution in the answer should work. If it still does not work for you, you can add `_email.less` file on the same level as `_typography.less` with the below content:

Comment: .wrapper-inner {
    .main-content, p, th, td {
        font-family: 'Sofia-pro', 'Sans-serif';
    }
}

Comment: Yes I need _email-*.less files in order to apply my custom styles on email templates.

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue but, adding _email.less also did not help. This is how the structure of my css and font dir looks [link](https://imgur.com/a/RGU0faL). 

The code in _typography.less is 
```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Sofia-pro',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/SofiaProRegular',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
);

```

The code in _variable.less is 

```
@font-family-name__base: 'Sofia-pro';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;

```

And the code in _email.less is what u gave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140123/discussion-between-tu-van-and-losmos).

Comment: @LosMos did you get it works?

Comment: It did work locally but, on real email client, the fonts were always overridden. Using Roboto from google did work. Now I have another issue regarding data patches and email templates. Could u maybe look into it please? [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361668/how-to-programatically-delete-an-email-template-from-admin-via-patch)

Comment: Ok, we'll jump to the Data patches issue first and back to this issue tomorrow.