# How to programatically delete an email template from admin via patch?

Tags: admin, email-templates, patches

I have patch for email template and I want to delete already existing email template via patch. I can also update the already existing one. I understand the process in theory to update that is, check if template exists, load it, apply changes and save it but, not sure how to do it in code. Also, not sure if I want to delete the email template via data patch, how to do it in code?

Below is what I have tried but, does not work.

```
  public function apply()
    {
        $email_template = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('aw_ca/email/new_company_user_created_template');
        $template = $this->templateFactory->create();
        $this->templateResource->load($template, $email_template);
        $templateText = $this->filesystem->fileGetContents($this->getDirectory(self::TEMPLATE_NAME . '.html'));
        $template->setTemplateCode('New Company User Invitation')->setTemplateSubject(self::TEMPLATE_SUBJECT)
            ->setTemplateText($templateText)->setTemplateType(TemplateInterface::TYPE_HTML);
        if($template->getTemplateCode() !== null) {
            $this->templateResource->delete($template);
            $this->configWriter->delete('aw_ca/email/new_company_user_created_template');
        }
        $this->templateResource->save($template);
        $this->configWriter->save('aw_ca/email/new_company_user_created_template', $template->getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this post I'll add 2 features:

- Delete an existing email template programmatically
- Update an existing email template programmatically

Please can choose one of these features as your need. Currently, I've commented out the delete feature to prevent you don't want to delete your existing email template.

You also don't need to save the email content in a separate HTML file, you can use [Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to declare content inside the Data Patch file.

The Data Patch file: `app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateEmailTemplate.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Email\Model\TemplateFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template as TemplateResource;

class UpdateEmailTemplate implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TemplateFactory
     */
    private $templateFactory;

    /**
     * @var TemplateResource
     */
    private $templateResource;

    public function __construct(
        TemplateResource $TemplateResource,
        TemplateFactory $templateFactory
    ) {
        $this->templateResource = $TemplateResource;
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $template = $this->templateFactory->create();
        $templateCode = 'New Order Customize'; // This is the Template Name in admin
        $this->templateResource->load($template, $templateCode, 'template_code');

        /* Choose one of the features below as your need */

        // 1. Delete an existing email template
//        if ($template->getId()) {
//            $this->templateResource->delete($template);
//        }

        // 2. Update an existing email template
        $content = <<<'HTML'
YOUR EMAIL TEMPLATE CONTENT GOES HERE
HTML;

        $template->setTemplateText($content);
        $this->templateResource->save($template);
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'template_code' do in this statement? `$this->templateResource->load($template, $templateCode, 'template_code');`. Is it supposed to be replaced by actual template code? Could u please explain this line a bit?

Comment: Ok, I understood what 'template_code' is. It refers to the field in the table whose value is the second parameter of load() method.

Comment: Hope you found it useful. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Yes, it was useful. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!